# Call a function before the page is timeout in PHP

Tags: php, php-5.3

I have a PHP script that will run for a long time. I have set the execution time limit to 5 minutes by using `set_time_limit()` function. I would like to ask whether I can set the script to call a function when timeout limit is reached? like the page unload script in JavaScript or viewDidUnload function in NSViewController, in iPhone SDK ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [register_shutdown_function()](http://php.net/register-shutdown-function) to register a callback, that is called, when the execution finishes. You should also have a look at [connection handling](http://php.net/features.connection-handling).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using [register_shutdown_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) But this isn't good practice, remeber that you will catch also fatal error, parse errors etc.